# Google Map Autofill

Tags: maps, autofill

Can anyone please help me out with this google autofill function? The function wasn't working when I tried to run it.

Is it the problem with the code?

I am a fresher and please do help me out.

```
<input type="text"  name="letsfrom" id="letsfrom" required> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places&language=en-AU"></script>
<script>
   var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete($("#address")[0], {});

   google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
       var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
       console.log(place.address_components);
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Please explain what exactly is not working. Is the script not running? Is it not doing what you want it to?

Comment: I don't get the auto fill suggestions from google.